# Recommended way to create a video stream using aws kinesis in the browser

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, webrtc, amazon-kinesis

I am trying to create a Kinesis Video Stream from my WebCam to the Server using JavaScript.
I am trying to use the Amazon Kinesis Video Streams WebRTC SDK for JavaScript repo in order to implement my solution along with the AWS SDK for JS v2 provided.

Is this sufficient to create a producer to stream to the AWS server or is there anything I am missing?

I have tried the WebRTC SDK test page to send my video to the server and it does not work for me.

Resources:
https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-kinesis-video-streams-webrtc-sdk-js.
https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesisvideostreams-webrtc-dg/latest/devguide/kvswebrtc-sdk-js.html